# Definition of a Turing Machine

Tags: discrete-mathematics, definition, computational-complexity

Could someone explain the following definition of a Turing Machine?

A Turing Machine $M$ is defined formally by a tuple $(\Sigma, Q, \delta)$
Where $\Sigma$ is a finite set representing the number of symbols that $M$'s tape can contain. We assume $\Sigma$ to contain a blank symbol as well as a start symbol. We call $\Sigma$ the *alphabet* of $M$.
And a finite set $Q$ of possible states of $M$'s register can be in. We assume that $\exists q_{start}, q_{halt} \in Q$
And $\delta$ is a function $\delta : Q \times \Sigma^k \to Q \times \Sigma^{k-1} \times \{L,S,R \}^k$

Anyone have any consensus on the definition?

Comment: How can we "explain" if you don't tell us which part you don't understand?

Comment: As if you were trying to explain it to someone unfamiliar with the overall concept.

Comment: @WillO I need to know this definition but do not know anything about it, what a tape is, the blank and start symbols, the states of the register, nor the function $\delta$

Comment: You can play with http://www.google.com/doodles/alan-turings-100th-birthday

Comment: Your definition may be wrong otherwise after $k$ steps transition, there's nothing on the tape.

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Definition pulled from page 16 http://www.math.sc.edu/~cooper/math778C/abct.pdf

Comment: @AnthonyPeter But I think there's enough explanation in the note, isn't it?